# Is an open ball on the integers open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M = (\mathbb Z, d)$ be a metric space where $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. Then, let an open ball $B_r(x) = \{y \in \mathbb Z : |x - y| < r\}$. There is a proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Open_Set/Metric_Space) stating that all open balls are open sets. However, I fail to see how this extends to all metric spaces, especially the integers. For example, $B_2(0) = \{-1,1\}$. This set is clearly not open, since each of its elements are not interior points.

The definition of open that I am using is: a set $E$ is open if every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$.

Please tell me where my reasoning is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integers with the metric topology you suggest are a *discrete* space. So *every* set is open, and in particular $\{-1,1\}$. To see this, note that if $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ and $|x-y|<1$, then it has to be the case that $x=y$. In other words, $\{x\}=B_1(x)$, so every singleton is open.

However, not every open set in a metric space is an open ball. Rather every open set in a metric space is a union of open balls. In this case, $\{-1,1\}=\{-1\}\cup\{1\}=B_1(-1)\cup B_1(1)$.

Comment: For discrete spaces, are subsets simply defined to be open sets?

Comment: Yes. A space is discrete if all the subsets are open. Equivalently, if all the singletons are open.

Comment: A point $p$ is an interior point of $E$ if there exists an $r$ such that $B_r(p) \subseteq E$

Comment: Good, now take $r=1$, and check to see if $-1$ and $1$ are interior points of $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: It's been a late night... thank you for making me see what has been in front of my eyes for hours.

Comment: You're welcome!